# How to identify the element When Class name is same?

Tags: xpath

I have 2 buttons signin and Reset..

```
<a class="dboxheader" href="javascript:setAction('ValidateUser')">Sign&nbsp;In</a>

<a class="dboxheader" href="javascript:setAction('Reset')">Reset</a>
```

I am using xpath `//a[@href='javascript:setAction('ValidateUser')']` to identify the the signin button.. Button getting below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //a[@href='javascript:setAction('ValidateUser')'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@href='javascript:setAction('ValidateUser')'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

How to resolve this???

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes inside single quoted string. Don't know how it works in selenium, but both xalan and saxon work well with following approach:

```
select='//a[@href="javascript:setAction(&apos;ValidateUser&apos;)"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the beauty of Relative Xpaths. Though class is same we can identify them easily by different methods.

Try below

```
//a[contains(text(),'Sign&nbsp;In')]
//a[contains(text(),'Reset')]
```

Comment: This is not working.. org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Sign&nbsp;In')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds

Comment: Use below code before you click on this Web-elements.      assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Sign&nbsp;In"));           And let me know the error message?

Comment: boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("Sign&nbsp;In");
System.out.println(b);  Result: False

Comment: boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("Sign In");
System.out.println("Exist of sign in text " + b); This returns true

Comment: So Button 'Sign&nbsp;In' is not in your current frame. Please switch to correct frame in which 'Sign&nbsp;In' is located and then  try to click on the Web-element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65816/discussion-between-changan-and-rupesh-shinde).

Comment: I have added screenshot